# React conditional Show/hide not working after input to form

Tags: javascript, reactjs

thanks for help in advance. I was trying to do component which shows button based on `const results` but when I insert: `Balaton` it shows only after I insert another char to the string. So the string is ```Balatons``

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Link as Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

//STYLES
import './Search.css'; 

// COMPONENTS
import Gallery from '../Gallery/Gallery';
import Present from '../Present/Present';

const results = ["Balaton", "Zamardi", "Sound", "Madarsko", "Sziget", "Hungary"]

class Search extends React.Component {
        state = {
            input: '',
            showButton: false
        };

    onInput = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            input: event.target.value})
        console.log(this.state.input)
        console.log(this.state.submit)

        // Conditional input to render button
        if (results.indexOf(this.state.input) > -1) {
            this.setState({
                showButton: true
            })
        } else {
            this.setState({
                showButton: false
            })
        }
    }

    // TODO
    // Handling submit event
    onSubmit = (event) => {
        console.log(this.state.submitted);
        event.preventDefault()
    }


    render() {

            return(
                    <div>
                        <form className="search-form" onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                            <input 
                                type="text" 
                                value={this.state.input} 
                                placeholder="Our great memory" 
                                onChange={this.onInput}
                            />
                        {this.state.showButton && <button>Button</button>}
                        </form>
                    </div>)

        }
}

export default Search;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setState is async method so when you test this.state.input you get the old value.
Try to use this:

```
// ....
onInput = (event) => {
    const eventValue = event.target.value;
    this.setState({
        input: eventValue })
    console.log(eventValue )
    console.log(this.state.submit)

    // Conditional input to render button
    if (results.indexOf(eventValue) > -1) {
        this.setState({
            showButton: true
        })
    } else {
        this.setState({
            showButton: false
        })
    }
}
// ....
```

or you can use the setState callback function:

```
// ....
onInput = (event) => {
    this.setState({
        input: event.target.value }, ()=> {
    console.log(this.state.input)
    console.log(this.state.submit)

     // Conditional input to render button
     if (results.indexOf(this.state.input) > -1) {
        this.setState({
            showButton: true
        })
     } else {
        this.setState({
            showButton: false
        })
     }
   })
}
// ....
```